# Username and Password for Repository

Tags: repository, salesforce

I was able to download eclipse to my pc but when trying to add repository dialog and its asking for username and password.

I am using Using eclipse 4.3.
I was able to download it and set it up but when following the instructions from the force.developer site it was asking me for a Username and password.

Comment: You will need to supply a lot more information in order for somebody to help you. What repository are you trying to add (SVN/GIT/CVS)?

Comment: I am following these instructions here:Eclipse Kepler (4.3) (Eclipse 4.3 download site)—the 'Eclipse IDE for Java Developers' distribution is strongly recommended
For more information on support, see the Release Notes.
[edit] Installation Steps
Launch Eclipse and click Help > Install New Software....

Install New Software
Click Add.In the Add Repository dialog, set the Name to "Force.com IDE" and the Location to "http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42" and click OK. (Use the same URL for Eclipse 4.3.)

Answer (score 1):

Purely a guess since you seam to have gone out of your way to not actually tell us what your trying to do or what you have already tried.

I have never used any of Salesforce.com's APIs or services, but I would guess the username/password it's asking for is the "Developer Edition" account mentioned near the bottom of this page:

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE

Comment: I really don't have much to say here. I have tried my developer password and username and I have also tried my Salesforce Username and Password. both don't work. I have spoken to few different people who have installed this and they were never asked for a username and password to set Eclipse up on their pc.